# Unable to use delve: pacakge main is not in GOROOT

Tags: go, delve

This is my directory structure:

```
root
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── acceptor.go
├── cmd
│   ├── main
│   └── main.go
├── go.mod
```

I want to debug `cmd/main`.

I tried:  `dlv debug main`.

I got an error:

```
package main is not in GOROOT (/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.15.5/libexec/src/main)
exit status 1
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call `dlv debug main`, you're telling delve to debug a package called `main` in the standard library, which obviously doesn't exist.

You must provide the full absolute, or relative path.

Absolute path:

```sh
dlv debug github.com/yourusername/root/cmd
```

Relative path:

```sh
dlv debug ./cmd
```